# How to have script wait until user interacts in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning Python on my own and now I'm trying to learn some GUI with Tkinter. If anyone can help, I'm having trouble having the program show a greeting message and then offering options that should be picked by clicking a button. Actually, I think I've sorted out how to build it, but there's a key piece missing: I don't know how to have the program wait until the user has interacted by clicking one of the buttons.

Let's say, for instance, I create a file with a 'Window' Class (for the interface) and some functions along (Window.py):

```py
import time
from tkinter import *

# Here I'll set each one of the the buttons' commands. 
# I've referenced it before to avoid triggering a reference problem, but when I tried, I actually broke the code in three parts and used imports to link all of them. 
# For simplicity's sake, however, I'll present everything in a single file in this question.  

Choice = ''

def Choose1():
    Choice = 1

def Choose2():
    Choice = 2

def Choose3():
    Choice = 3

# Here I create the object 'Window':

class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.title = 'Interact'
        self.Window.minsize = (500, 300)
        # Here I'll add a label to display the messages that I want to show the user:  
        self.Text = Label(self.Window, text = '')
        self.Text.pack()
        # Aqui uma série de botões:
        self.B1 = Button(self.Window, text = 'Option 1', command = Choose1)
        self.B1.pack()
        self.B2 = Button(self.Window, text = 'Option 2', command = Choose2)
        self.B2.pack()
        self.B3 = Button(self.Window, text = 'Option 3', command = Choose3)
        self.B3.pack()

# Here I'll create an instance of the 'Window' object:  

Example = Window()

# Here I'll create a function so that certain messages will be displayed to the user:

def Say(X):
    Example.Text.configure(text = X)
    Example.Text.update()
    time.sleep(3) # Please ignore this. I inserted this delay so there's time for the user to read the message. I actualy have a better way to do it, but to keep it simple, let's leave it like this.

# Finally, the main part of the program:

Say('Welcome!')
Say('Which option would you like to choose?')
WaitInput() # I haven't figured out how this function would work, and that's my issue. I'd like the program to wait for the option to be chosen and only then print the following message:
Say('You've chosen option {}!'.format(Choose))

Text.mainloop()
```

Can anybody by any chance tell me how can I create this 'WaitInput()' function, or if something of the sort already exists in Python?

Appreciate it!

Comment: `command=` needs function's name without `()` and arguments (it is called `callback`) and tkinter will use later `()` to run this function. If you have to assign function with arguments then use `lambda` - `command=lambda:Choose('3')`

Comment: `mainloop()` starts program - it shows window. You should rateher use `root.after(milliseconds, callback)` instead of `sleep`

Comment: you should display `You've chosen option` inside `Choose()`

Comment: Thanks, furas. I'll make the necessary adaptations as you pointed out. My only issue is with your third comment - I mean, that solution may solve this particular instance of the problem, but if I'm not mistaken, if I want to repeatedly present different alternatives after that one, I would have to create countless 'Choose()'-like functions to have the user interact with the GUI. I was hoping I could find some kind of pause like the input() function does - if there's such a thing. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: all GUIs work different then `input()`. Did you see pause in Excel or Chrome? `input()` has to do only one thing - wait for text - but GUI has to do many things in the same time - mainloop has to all time get key/mouse events from system, send them to widgets and redraw widgets. Only `after()` doesn't block `mainloop` because it keep it on list and compare with current time to see if it is time to execute assigned function.

Comment: Humm... I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all GUIs (in all languages) you use button to wait for input and execute some function when there are input data.

In `tkinter` you have to use `lambda` to assing function with arguments to button

```
self.b1 = tk.Button(self.window, text='Option 1', command=lambda:self.choose('1'))
```

---

I used `after()` to change text with delay and also to add buttons with delay - I used `callback` in `say_later()` to execute it with delay.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title = 'Interact'
        self.window.geometry('500x300')
        #self.window.minsize = (500, 300)

        self.text = tk.Label(self.window, text='')
        self.text.pack()

    def add_buttons(self):
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.window, text='Option 1', command=lambda:self.choose('1'))
        self.b1.pack()
        self.b2 = tk.Button(self.window, text='Option 2', command=lambda:self.choose('2'))
        self.b2.pack()
        self.b3 = tk.Button(self.window, text='Option 3', command=lambda:self.choose('3'))
        self.b3.pack()

    def say(self, message, callback=None):
        self.text.configure(text=message)
        if callback:
            callback()

    def say_later(self, delay, message, callback=None):
        self.window.after(delay, lambda:self.say(message, callback))

    def choose(self, value):
        self.say("You've chosen option {}!".format(value))

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main --- 

example = Window()

example.say('Welcome!')
example.say_later(3000, 'Which option would you like to choose?', example.add_buttons)

example.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks furas! It took me some time to answer because I was stuck trying to process what you said in your last comments. I'm learning everything in python by reading and watching tutorials - It's my first programming language, so I hadn't thought about the code architecture the way you described yet. Now - after some time drafting everything - your solution does make much more sense than what I thought originally. Guess I have to think more GUI and less 'Python Terminal' now! Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: _"In tkinter you have to use lambda "_ - that's not entirely true. You _can_ use lambda, but there are other ways to do it. To say you "have to" use lambda is incorrect.